# Mishmaros and Leap Years

Tags: beis-hamikdash, temple-service-avoda

So there were 24 mishmaros in the BHMK, and both kohanim, leviim went 2x a year, along with ma'amados of Yisraelim.
This work for a shana peshutah, but what about for a shana meuberes?
Does the mishmar just shift to the next family, or is there another system for this?
What about the ma'amados?

Comment: A year is 50-51 weeks not 48.

Comment: @Chatzkel yom tov doesn't count, but still not an exact match

Comment: @DoubleAA really? The Mishnah says that the mishmar of YT would get the lechem hapanim

Comment: Anyway, from the Mishnah that says whoever was the mishmar by yovel would get the lands of hekdesh, it would seem that it wasn’t pre ordained. They kept going week by week, and each year  it would be different weeks. So a leap year was no different

Comment: @chatzkel which?doesn't sukkat 5:7 say the opposite

Comment: @DoubleAA it does say the opposite with regard to the lechem hapanim, but there still was a משמר שזמנו קבוע who gets other stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular year is 353, 354, or 355 days which is 50 weeks plus 3, 4, or 5 days. The extra days are therefore part of the first mishmar of the next year. A leap year is 383, 384, or 385 days which is 54 weeks (+ 5 days), 54 weeks (+ 6 days), or 55 weeks even. The mishmaros (and ma'amados) therefore just continue week by week with no special changes. Each shabbos goes to the next family each week.